# Parent node is null after replaceWith jQuery method

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm using jQuery to manipulate DOM in my project. I've got class method, that works like this:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->    
var template = this._Template.split('{0}');
    var content = template[0] + this._Content + template[1];
    if (!this._BlockNode) {
        this._BlockNode = $(content);
        this._ParentNode.append(this._BlockNode);
    }
    else {
        this._BlockNode.replaceWith(content);
    }
```

Everything is ok on the first call of this method, because it creates node and appends it to parent node. The second call (using `replaceWith()` method) works ok too. But after it property `this._BlockNode[0].parentNode` is null. So when I call it third time and `replaceWith()` works with new `_.BlockNode` without `.parentNode` property it does not replace content of node because of this check: `if ( !isDisconnected( this[0] ) ) { //line 5910 in jQuery 1.8.3`.
How to deal with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ensure that `_BlockNode` always points to the *current* version of the content.

When you call `replaceWith` you correctly update the DOM structure, but fail to update the contents of your object.  The original `_BlockNode` ends up orphaned, and all subsequent `replaceWith` calls work on that node and not on the newer content.

Try this:

```
var template = this._Template.split('{0}');
var $content = $(template[0] + this._Content + template[1]);
if (!this._BlockNode) {
    this._ParentNode.append($content);
} else {
    this._BlockNode.replaceWith($content);
}
this._BlockNode = $content;
```

It *may* be preferable to hold a native DOM element in `_BlockNode` rather than a jQuery object.